# Unable to get particleground javascript as background for div/section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am trying to get the background of a specific div on my website to be the particleground jquery background - http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2014/08/18/particleground-jquery-plugin-background-particle-systems/ . I followed the steps from here and copied the script correctly, but instead of the background showing up behind the text in a div, it forms another div or section right above it. Troubleshooting steps included; adding a div before the section declaration and giving it the ID="particle", adding a div after the section declaration and giving it the ID="particle". Also making the z-index of each of these divs 1. Here is the HTML for the section :

```
<div id="particle">
<section class="container-fluid about">
    <div class="container parallax-window " data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="/images/parallax.jpg" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p>From concept to roll out, GM Motors...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
section.about {
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #00a1de;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 80px; }
```

Help would be appreciated.

```
  section.about p {
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 300; }
```

Comment: Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I've created a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/s8t47o5e) for the **particleground** effect you're seeking.

By making a slight change in your **CSS** you can easily achieve that:

```
section.about {
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     top: 50%;
     padding: 0 20px;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
 }
```

Since reading your que I came to realize that you're using *bootstrap* so I've also added *bootstrap* library to check it is supported by *particleground* or not.

Please have a look. It will do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks @vivekkupadhyay :) Is there a way, I can move the text higher in the div ?

Comment: @Shashank its all about **CSS** now..all you've to do is just play with it :)