# How to Enable smooth scrolling on a HTML5 Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

I am working on a project that has a page which uses a premade jquery background which has scrolling disabled by the author.
I have tried all the tricks with **`overflow:`** property but was unable to correct and achieve a smooth scrolling effect without disturbing the animation symmetry of the whole page.

**Demo Code**: [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/yjwfpjh0/)

Please direct me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be cool to mention from where did you get the [code](http://jnicol.github.io/particleground/). You just copied the whole structure without mentioning it anywhere.

As far as I have understood the author of this plugin, it's meant to have this *particleground* plugin applied only to the header not to the whole page. I guess you should rethink what you're trying to achieve.

By the way there are people who tried to achieve something similar to idea like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664542/unable-to-get-particleground-javascript-as-background-for-div-section).

Comment: I have already mentioned in my query that this method didn't work out!